# What is the x-thread:// URL scheme?

Tags: url-scheme

A website's private messaging notification was emailed to me with links to reply to the message and access the web's messaging thread which both start with x-thread:// URL scheme. Clicking them on Gmail android app did nothing, another mail app gave me "ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME". A desktop client and online Gmail opens it with usual http://... I've tried searching Google but it yielded no relevant result. Google's autocomplete feature shows that various addresses of this sort had already been searched before. So what is this?

Comment: That happened to me too, I feel like it's some sort of scam for unwanted publicity.